# how to fix server time with Php (GMT)

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I use this PHP code to put on DB the timestamp,  the issue I see the time with 2 hours difference. 
the hosting server clock is not set right.
how do you add hours timestamp forward?
or any better way to get accurate time. (GMT +2)

> date_default_timezone_set('TZ=Asia/Tel_Aviv');

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

  $sql = "INSERT INTO enterlog (ItemCode, EnterDate, IPAddress) VALUES
 ('$itemCode', '$time', '$IP')";
```

I want to fix 2015-11-03 07:29:21 to 2015-11-03 09:29:21,

Comment: What is your default timezone??

Comment: UTC +2 (changes on summer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
bool date_default_timezone_set(string $timezone_identifier);
```

Comment: I tried this date_default_timezone_set('TZ=Asia/Tel_Aviv'); 
still I get latency

Comment: @eyalix if I'm not mistaken, you'll only want to do `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tel_Aviv')`, so without the `TZ`

Comment: @Phroggyy Yes, It works now, It gives fixed time after removing TZ